# Delete all occurrences of value in Swift Array

Tags: arrays, swift

So I have an array of Int's and I am trying to create a function to delete a certain value from the array. However, the removeAtIndex() function only deletes the first occurrence and the removeLast() only removes the last. I tried enumerating through the array but I end up with an Array index out of range error, possible due to the reshifting that occurs when deleting an item from the array.

```
  for (index, value) in connectionTypeIDs.enumerate() {
            if (value == connectionTypeToDelete){
                connectionTypeIDs.removeAtIndex(index)
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The quickest way is to use filter. I don't know is that answer your question but you can have a look on this:

```
// remove 1 from array
arr = arr.filter{$0 != 1}
```

Comment: In Swift, you *can* mutate an array during enumeration. The problem is that the indexes don't match anymore.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, I didn't know that. I updated my answer.

Comment: That seemed to work! Thanks! :)

Comment: That's cool. Thanks.